# Remove background-color from string in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I want to remove background-color attribute from string (html) 
example :

```
<p style=\"background-color:#eeeeee\">Hellow world</p>
```

will be

```
<p >Hellow world</p>
```

or

```
<p style=\"\">Hellow world</p>
```

in c#

Comment: What have you attempted thus far?

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex is dangerous, it can easily summon ZALGO.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/26742).

Comment: Is there any way other regex?

Comment: What @Vlad said. A Google search for `parse html c#` brought up [Html Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/)

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the style-attribute with the XmlDocument class.
For a whole page, it will be the challenge to find the right nodes to do so. (Maybe run though child nodes recursively..) But here an example of the string you posted - to remove the style:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml("<p style=\"background-color:#eeeeee\">Hellow world</p>");
        var attributesofFirst = xml.ChildNodes[0].Attributes;
        attributesofFirst.RemoveNamedItem("style");
        Console.WriteLine(xml.ChildNodes[0].OuterXml); //<p>Hellow world</p>  
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```